# How to append int32 data to protobuf JS bytebuffer message

Tags: javascript, angularjs, protocol-buffers, arraybuffer

Hello javascript masters,

I'm trying to generate a protobuf-based file using javascript, which has the following strutcture:

messageSize | probuff bytes | messageSize | protobuff bytes .. etc

The idea is that I'm appending multiple protobuf messages in just one file, to later process it by reading the message size (4 bytes integer), and then rebuild the pb message by reading the respective following bytes, later decoding each message with protobuf.

I already have the coding/decoding working in Objective-C but I'm struggling to do the same with javascript. Since code speaks for itself, here's how it's done with Objc (using pod 'ProtocolBuffers', '~> 1.9.8'), in each iteration:

```
//configure protobuff, then build.
DataOperationPB * dataOp = [dataOperationBuilder build];
//get its NSData representation
NSData * varBlob = [dataOp data]; //byte string

unsigned int size = (unsigned int)[dataOp serializedSize];
[variablesBlobContainer appendData:[NSMutableData dataWithBytes:&size length:sizeof(size)]];
[variablesBlobContainer appendData:varBlob];

//then we can easily write this to a file with: 
[variablesBlobContainer writeToFile:fileNameWithPath atomically:YES]
```

So easy; If I open the generated file, and say the first protobuffer message' size is 250, the initial data in the file is correctly seen:

Viewing the first 4 bytes of the file (offset 0) in HEX :

> FA 00 00 00

And as INT (LITTLE ENDIAN):

> 250

Works as expected. I got decoding working with python as well, if you're more comfortable with that language (removed asserts for brevity):

```
 file = open(currentPbdFile, 'r')
                    msgSize = file.read(4)
                    msg_len = struct.unpack('<L',msgSize)[0]
                    while msg_len > 0:
                            bufferVar = file.read(msg_len)
                            dataOpList.append(DataOperation(bufferVar))
                            msgSize = file.read(4)

                            if(msgSize == ''):
                                    break
                            msg_len = struct.unpack('<L', msgSize)[0]
```

Now, when trying the same with javascript I'm struggling with it. One of my attempts was (using [protobuf.js](https://github.com/dcodeIO/ProtoBuf.js/) to encode the messages):

```
var ProtoBuf = dcodeIO.ProtoBuf;
var builder = ProtoBuf.loadProtoFile("DataOperationPB.proto");

var ByteBuffer = dcodeIO.ByteBuffer;
var byteBuffer = new ByteBuffer(ByteBuffer.DEFAULT_CAPACITY, ByteBuffer.LITTLE_ENDIAN);
var data = new DataOperationPB({
                //(omitted code for setting pb message values)
            });
```

Then in a loop I build the message and append the data:

```
byteBuffer.append(new ByteBuffer().writeInt32(data.calculate()));
byteBuffer.append(data.encode()); //the protobuff data itself
```

Later on I provide the data as an url download button:

```
var data = new Blob([new DataView(byteBuffer.toArrayBuffer())], {type: 'application/octet-stream'});
```

From angular:

```
this.url = ($window.URL || $window.webkitURL).createObjectURL(data);
```

When I open the downloaded file for a 29-length protobuff message, the first four bytes looks like this:

> 28 01 38 04

Which is, completely wrong.

Digging a bit further I noticed that [protobuf.js](https://github.com/dcodeIO/ProtoBuf.js/) uses their own implementation of ArrayBuffers (called [ByteBuffer.js](https://github.com/dcodeIO/ByteBuffer.js)), which in turn uses the normal ArrayBuffers when running Javascript in the browser. Me not being senior in JS, could anyone please point in the the direction to accomplish the aforementioned? Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 2):

Answering my own question.. the developer of the library helped me figure it out.

The trap I felt into was not noticing that the .toArrayBuffer() method effectively needs to perform a read, and when switching from/to write/read operations a flip() is necessary, here:

```
//the important, forgotten flip() - 'implicit' read operation:
new Blob([new DataView(byteBuffer.flip().toArrayBuffer())]
```

Additionally, when using .writeInt32() directly, no flip is required, whereas appending a newly created byteBuffer requires:

```
for(...){
    byteBuffer.writeInt32(data.calculate());
    // -- or --
    byteBuffer.append(new ByteBuffer(ByteBuffer.DEFAULT_CAPACITY, ByteBuffer.LITTLE_ENDIAN).writeInt32(data.calculate()).flip());
}
```

[Here](https://github.com/dcodeIO/ByteBuffer.js/wiki/Offset-and-limit) is more documentation about it. Hope this helps somebody.

Best regards!